# Applicable OpenLayers settings for WFS layer

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs, gml

I am trying to display a WFS layer on an OpenLayers map. Here are the appropriate portions of *GETCAPABILITIES* response.

```
<ows:Operation name="GetFeature">
  <ows:DCP>
    <ows:HTTP>
      <ows:Get xlink:href="http://localhost/MapServer/Default.aspx"/>
      <ows:Post xlink:href="http://localhost/MapServer/Default.aspx"/>
    </ows:HTTP>
  </ows:DCP>
  <ows:Parameter name="resultType">
    <ows:Value>results</ows:Value>
    <ows:Value>hits</ows:Value>
  </ows:Parameter>
  <ows:Parameter name="outputFormat">
    <ows:Value>text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1</ows:Value>
  </ows:Parameter>
</ows:Operation>
<ows:Parameter name="srsName">
  <ows:Value>EPSG:4326</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Constraint name="DefaultMaxFeatures">
  <ows:Value>20000</ows:Value>
</ows:Constraint>
```

The feature I am trying to display:

```
<wfs:FeatureType>
  <wfs:Name>Data_ACTIVE</wfs:Name>
  <wfs:Title/>
  <wfs:Abstract/>
  <ows:Keywords/>
  <wfs:DefaultSRS>EPSG:4326</wfs:DefaultSRS>
  <wfs:OutputFormats>
    <wfs:Format>text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1</wfs:Format>
  </wfs:OutputFormats>
  <ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
    <ows:LowerCorner>-102.01545715332 28.970645904541</ows:LowerCorner>
    <ows:UpperCorner>-71.021598815918 43.1671752929688</ows:UpperCorner>
  </ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
</wfs:FeatureType>
```

**Here is the code I am using:**

```
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        // allow testing of specific renderers via "?renderer=Canvas", etc
        var renderer = OpenLayers.Util.getParameters(window.location.href).renderer;
        renderer = (renderer) ? [renderer] : OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers;
        var geographic = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
        var mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");

        map = new OpenLayers.Map({
            div: "map",
            layers: [
                new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("OpenLayers WMS",
                    "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
                    { layers: "basic" }
                ),
                new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GML", {
                    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                            url: "http://localhost/MapServer/Default.aspx",
                            featureType: "Data_ACTIVE",
                            featureNS: "http://www.tstgis.org/gml",
                            version: "1.1.0",
                            geometryName: "line"
                        }),
                        renderers: renderer
                    })
            ],
            zoom: 15
        });

        var bb = new OpenLayers.Bounds(-179.821327209473, 12.1057098342161, -56.5289154052734, 78.1442901657839);
        map.zoomToExtent(bb);
});
```

I see a post request being made to the server for the layer and a result coming back but it is not displayed at all. Why would the layer not show? Any help would be appreciated.

**NOTE**
This test script is part of an HTML shell that is running under localhost/mapserver, so it rules out the familiar cross-domain issue.

Comment: Because you offer *identical* answers to this and another question at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49556/wfs-layer-in-openlayers-queries-server-for-data-but-doesnt-display-the-data/50191#50191, I take that as *prima facie* evidence that the two threads are duplicates.  Which one would you like to leave open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no doubt that this was a configuration issue with OpenLayers. From what I knew about OpenLayers, I had it configured properly. Turns out, it is essential, in my case, to set the featurePrefix option. The reason for this is that the namespace and prefix in the XML response (GML) for each FeatureMember Node is used to identify the appropriate reader for the response. By default, the featurePrefix is set to ‘feature’. If the response's namespace + prefix does not match the configuration in OpenLayers, the features are not added to the layer and hence not displayed. In my case, the prefix is set to an empty string as the server does not add a prefix to the response.

Also, setting the geometryName is critical. The default value for geometryName is ‘the_geom’ for WFS version 1.0, and null for higher versions. The geometryName is used by the server to actually locate the features. In my case, geometryName used on the server was "msGeometry".

Here is the working code.

```
$(document).ready(
function () {
    // allow testing of specific renderers via "?renderer=Canvas", etc
    var renderer = OpenLayers.Util.getParameters(window.location.href).renderer;
    renderer = (renderer) ? [renderer] : OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers;
    var geographic = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
    var mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");

    map = new OpenLayers.Map({
        div: "map",
        layers: [
            new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("OpenLayers WMS",
                "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
                { layers: "basic" }
            ),
            new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GML", {
                strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                        url: "http://localhost/MapServer/Default.aspx",
                        featureType: "Data_ACTIVE",
                        version: "1.1.0",
                        geometryName: "msGeometry",
                        featurePrefix: ""
                    }),
                    renderers: renderer
                })
        ],
        zoom: 15
    });

    var bb = new OpenLayers.Bounds(-179.821327209473, 12.1057098342161, -56.5289154052734, 78.1442901657839);
    map.zoomToExtent(bb);
```

});

Answer (score 2):

Your OpenLayers map will be drawn by default in Google Mercator. But your layer is Lat Long (EPSG:4326). So here is the problem.
You have the problem described and resolved [here](http://geographika.co.uk/mapserver-openlayers-and-the-wfs-maze).

Comment: thank you for your response. Without touching the server side, I added the following 2 items to my client side code. <br>
  WFS layer definition
    srsName: EPSG:900913
    url: url + "?srsName=\"EPSG:900913\""
<br>
Still no success though. From what I understand, EPSG:4326 and EPSG:900913 are inter-controvertible in OpenLayers and I am wonder how to do that client side. Any ideas about how to proceed further? Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One more thing, this the request made to the WMS layer:    /wms/vmap0?LAYERS=basic&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&EXCEPTIONS=application%2Fvnd.ogc.se_inimage&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=-135,45,-90,90&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256


From the request, I gather that it is requesting EPSG:4326 and not Mercator (EPSG:900913). I am at a loss as to where the problem might lie.

Comment: Niculita, reading through the mentioned blog post helped me understand various things but in my case, the problem was not about Multiple Spatial Reference Systems. Please, see my answer below. Thanks for your help.